# Select values out of XML column

Tags: xml, sql-server-2005

This is the structure of my table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TableA]
(
    [ObjectID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CGPracticeCode] [varchar](5) NULL,
    [TotalAmt] [decimal](11, 2) NULL,
    [SplitAmt] [xml] NULL,
)
```

The value in the SplitAmt Column are in the below format, no of rows may vary

```
'<Values>
  <Row>
    <PracticeCode>BE9</PracticeCode>
    <Value>20</Value>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <PracticeCode>BEA</PracticeCode>
    <Value>3</Value>
  </Row>
</Values>'
```

Now How do I get values like this... (No problem in repeating 1st 3 columns)

```
ObjectID, CGPracticeCode, TotalAmt, PracticeCode, [Value]
```

Comment: So you have multiple PracticeCode and Value for each ObjectId?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [this article by Alex Homer](http://www.15seconds.com/issue/050803.htm)

To return the first Row elements you can use:

```
select a.ObjectId, 
       a.CGPracticeCode, 
       a.TotalAmt, 
       a.SplitAmt.value('(/Values/Row/PracticeCode)[1]', 'nvarchar(50)') as PracticeCode, 
       a.SplitAmt.value('(/Values/Row/Value)[1]', 'int') as [Value]
from [dbo].[TableA] a
```